# Error while running npm command after installing node js

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting this error while running the npm command, I have searched the web but the solutions did not help, any idea what's causing this error?

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\path-scurry\node_modules\lru-cache\dist\cjs\index.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1181:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:591:14)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:668:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\path-scurry\dist\cjs\index.js:27:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\path-scurry\\node_modules\\lru-cache\\package.json'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\path-scurry\node_modules\lru-cache\dist\cjs\index.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1181:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:591:14)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:668:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\path-scurry\dist\cjs\index.js:27:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\path-scurry\\node_modules\\lru-cache\\package.json'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

Tried running npm command to see if Node.js was installed correctly